# Teleportation script randomly stopped working today

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I made a teleportation script yesterday, tested it, and then went to sleep, now it doesn't work and it simply outputs the message "Script 'Workspace.first.Script', Line 11" and "Cfrane is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.davidechko". Is it possible I broke it somehow?

```
1 second=game.Workspace.second
2 hit = script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
3   local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
4   if player then
5       local travelling = player.Character:FindFirstChild("travelling")
6       if not travelling then return end
7
8       
9       if travelling.Value == false then
10          travelling.Value = true
11          player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Cframe = second.CFrame + Vector3.new (0,5,0)
12          task.wait(3)
13          travelling.Value = false 
14      end
15  end
16 end)
```

is it possible I changed something that broke it?

I tried changing it around a little but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you did "Cframe" not "CFrame"

```
   local second = game.Workspace.second
    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
       local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
       if player then
           local travelling = player.Character:FindFirstChild("travelling")
           if not travelling then return end
           if travelling.Value == false then
              travelling.Value = true
              player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = second.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,5,0)
              task.wait(3)
              travelling.Value = false 
          end
      end
     end)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).